# Setting text to specific part of array list

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to set the text of a jTextField to a randomly chosen item of an Array list "sQuestions" the random part is complete since it needs to be made to correspond to the set text, I imagined it would be something like `questions.setText(sQuestions[n])` but then I had to add the `.toString()` part and now I don't know how to call the specific part of `sQuestions` as opposed to the whole array appearing.

```
Random randNum = new Random();
    if("science".equals(Choice)){
        int n = randNum.nextInt(sAnswers.size());
    }
ArrayList<String> sQuestions = new ArrayList<>();
questions.setText(sQuestions.toString());
```

Comment: What is your question actually? Please be a more clear about what you expect from the answer.

Comment: Put also the random part of your code. With this, it's impossible to know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to read it 4 times, but to my best guess, you want something like this:

```
Random r = new Random();
int randIndex = r.nextInt(sQuestions.size());

questions.setText(sQuestions.get(randIndex).toString());
```

If you have an ArrayList of Strings, which I suspect you do, you can leave the `toString()` part out.

Comment: I originally had the .toString() part left out but it made me add it. However I'll try .get(randIndex)

Comment: That's because JTextField's setText method expects a String as input, not an ArrayList of Strings =)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Random#nextInt(int)` to choose a random index on the list:

```
Random r = new Random();
int radnomIndex = r.nextInt(sQuestions.size());
sQuestions.get(randomIndex).setText("some text");
```